# How to declare local variable in closure javascript template

Tags: google-closure-templates

I started learning closure javascript template library . 
Is it possible to create local variable inside a closure template soy file ?
I tried using

```
$i=1;
```

but it prints `$i=1` on screen in place of declaring it.

I had looked inside examples at 
http://code.google.com/p/closure-templates/source/browse/trunk/examples/features.soy 
but didn't find same type of example.

Comment: I think local variables are not covered in the current template iteration. Prove me wrong - please! ;)

Answer (score 16):

Yes, this is now possible! If you have a build of [Closure Templates that was cut in 2011](http://code.google.com/p/closure-templates/source/list), you can declare local variables as follows:

```
{let $first: $person.firstName /}
{$first}
```

Note that like `{param}`, you can also define a local variable with a more complex expression between opening and closing tags:

```
{let $name}
  {$person.firstName} {$person.lastName}
{/let}
```

Sometimes you need to use this form if you want to use other commands to define your variable:

```
{let $className}
  {css name_class}
{/let}

<div class="{$name_class}"></div>
```

For more information about using `let` visit [project's documentation](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/commands#let)

Comment: Thanks! It's actually a bit worrying that the documentation is still not updated, but at least the feature is there... ^^

Comment: isnt this the documentation - https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/commands#let ?